# How to configure UglifyJS 2 to only concatenate in C#?

Tags: c#, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2, bundletransformer

I'm using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) for the [Bundle Transformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%3A%20UglifyJS) NuGet package within my C# project and I just want to be able to concatenate my JS files without minifying them for my QA environment, but I can't figure out how to do it. Is it possible?

Here is my current Web.config section for the Bundle Transformer:

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
<core>
  <css defaultMinifier="WgCssMinifier" usePreMinifiedFiles="true">
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
      <add name="SassAndScssTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.SassAndScss.Translators.SassAndScssTranslator, BundleTransformer.SassAndScss" />
    </translators>
    <postProcessors>
      <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="false" />
    </postProcessors>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
      <add name="WgCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.WG.Minifiers.WgCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.WG" />
    </minifiers>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
      <add fileExtension=".sass" assetTypeCode="Sass" />
      <add fileExtension=".scss" assetTypeCode="Scss" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </css>
  <js defaultMinifier="UglifyJsMinifier" usePreMinifiedFiles="true">
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
    </translators>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
      <add name="UglifyJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.UglifyJs.Minifiers.UglifyJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.UglifyJs" />
    </minifiers>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </js>
  <assetHandler disableServerCache="false" serverCacheDurationInMinutes="15" disableClientCache="false" />
</core>
<uglify>
  <js screwIe8="true" keepFunctionNames="false" severity="0">
    <parsing strict="false" bareReturns="false" />
    <compression compress="false" angular="true" />
    <mangling mangle="false" />
    <codeGeneration beautify="true" comments="all" />
  </js>
  <jsEngine name="V8JsEngine" />
</uglify>
<webGrease>
  <css shouldMinify="true" ejectCharset="true" />
</webGrease>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following settings:

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
    ...
    <js defaultMinifier="NullMinifier" ...>
      ...
    </js>
    ...
  </core>
  ...
</bundleTransformer>
```